# Using class static const members to create safe enum

Tags: c++, c++11, static, enums, constants

I've been using enums recently, and I came to the realization that enums, even enum classes, are inherently unsafe.

In fact, it is easy to do something like this:

```
enum class EnumType {
    A,
    B,
};

...
EnumType x = static_cast<EnumType>(10000);
```

This means that, in every piece of code that receives an `EnumType` variable there is potentially the need to check what the value contained is, because it could be outside of the values that have been specified by the user. This seems strange for a construct whose only objective is to create a new type.

So I tried to build an equivalent, and to my surprise it was very easy to do:

```
class ClassType final {
    public:
         ClassType() = delete;

         bool operator==(const ClassType & x) { return x.id == id; }       

         static const ClassType A;
         static const ClassType B;
    private:
         ClassType(int x) : id(x) {}
         int id;
};

const ClassType ClassType::A(0);
const ClassType ClassType::B(1);
```

Now every `ClassType` variable will always contain a valid value, you can't create variables containing non-valid values, and you can only copy between already valid values. It is also easy to create new valid elements, and also easy to define custom operations/casts, which is a thing that standard enums don't really let you do. And the whole overhead I think is minimal, and if this was a feature of the language it could probably be reduced even more.

The question is: why don't enums work like this out of the box, given that (I think) this would be the behaviour that anybody expects out of them? It's not even a matter of back-compatibility, given that c++11 introduced a new construct for them.

Comment: `EnumType x = (EnumType) 10000;`  To be fair, C-style casts make *all* C++ constructs inherently unsafe.

Comment: @DrewDormann Well, I don't think you can (at least not as easily?) cast from whatever base type to a class type, unless you specifically create the cast operator for it, can you?

Comment: Static initialization seems much more likely to go wrong than some silly casting.

Comment: @Svalorzen In your solution, it could look like this. `ClassType c = *(ClassType*)&some_invalid_int;`

Comment: @Pubby Most enums have explicitly defined int conversion for each single value, which are typed pretty much in the same way as static initialization. You can make mistakes creating an enum just as easily as here.

Comment: With your method, you cannot (easily) convert from integers to enumeration values at run-time. This is the only purpose of the **explicit** conversion `EnumType x = static_cast<EnumType>(10000);`. If there's an explicit cast, IMO that indicates there may be problems (which have been considered). There's always a way to get invalid values.

Comment: @Dyp If you need that, you can simply put the integer constructor public and list all the values that are allowed for the object, and throw otherwise. This ensures the internal consistency of the value.

Comment: @DrewDormann Got me there. But I was perplexed also because it works with `static_cast`. I'll update my question then.

Comment: @Svalorzen If you're updating the question, also consider that in your solution, the *definition itself* requires memory overhead and can't be inlined.  I think the *general answer* that you're looking for is that any of the protections that you're seeking from the language would require either memory or processing overhead that may not be wanted.

Comment: @DrewDormann But that's exactly the problem, isn't it? My solution requires memory, but that's simply because the language doesn't offer the same functionality built-in for an enum.

Comment: The `enum` (whether scoped or unscoped) is a type that doesn't cost you anything for any usage (compared to an integer). I would use it as a base type (member) to build this kind of class if a run-time check was necessary.